# Will adding a gas line wick heat out of my house?

Tags: energy-efficiency, temperature

I am looking at running a gas line into my house.

One concern I have is that having a big metal thing with a pipe on the outside leading into my basement will wick heat out of my house. I have had a problem with my garden faucet wicking heat out of the house and it is much smaller than the gas line will be.

I could potentially lead the pipe under 2 feet of earth before bringing it into the basement.

Comment: Regarding my edits... 'cold' isn't a thing. It doesn't exist and can't move. It makes for clearer conversation and better understanding to talk about heat conduction and transfer instead.

Answer (score 4):

Keep in mind what the pipes were made of and what they were full of.

Copper is nearly the best conductor on earth, and the pipe was full of water, which is *literally the best heat transfer fluid known to exist*, and also convects, i.e. circulates freely.

Iron is not as good a thermal conductor, the pipe will be much thicker, and natural gas is a fairly terrible heat transfer fluid.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the great theoretical answer from Harper, I can add that my practical experience is that as little as a few inches into the basement, the pipe does not feel any colder than the ambient air.  Also, there has never been any condensation, even when the shower it runs over is putting lots of steam in the air.

By the way, this is in southern Vermont (northeast US) where it sometimes gets very cold, but you didn't say where you were, but your profile says Cambridge, Mass, I used to live there, so if it's Cantabridgia, it doesn't get nearly as cold as it does here.